# Processing Plain Text

Tags: macros

I'm currently trying to typeset a plain text file that has a certain structure. There's one thing that I can't get working, and that is the following. My plain text is structures as follows:

```
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)


Title

"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)
```

So every section in my document has a title above it (seperated by a "/newline"), and every section is seperated from the other section by two times this.

Basically I'm trying to convert the above to:

```
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)

\section{Title}
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)
```

Would it be possible to do something like this?

Comment: this would be ridiculously simple to format with plain tex.  do you have any need for any particular latex features, or strong desire to use latex instead of plain tex?  more relevant to the content of the file, is there only one paragraph in a section, or could there be more than one, and if more than one, how do you want the paragraph separation to be distinguished?  by a blank line, or is an indentation okay?  (by the way, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436))

Comment: Hm... I would probably use `sed` or `perl` or something like that: `perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's/\n\n\n(.*)\n\n/\n\n\\section{\1}\n/' plain.txt` would reformat `plain.txt` as desired, but keep a `plain.bak` backup file in case something goes wrong. If you are using Windows line endings, the RegEx may have to be adapted, though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you not use Plain-style `\def`initions to insert the necessary `\section` directives?

Comment: Thanks for the answers Barbara en @daniel. It's basically a diary I'm trying to convert, so you could say every entry is it's own section. I tried your suggestion Daniel, and it worked!

Comment: @SeanAllred -- it seems i jumped to an unwarranted conclusion, that it was the tex processing that was wanted, not the transformation to tex coding.  however, it's actually possible to process this *without* inserting any tex commands, provided none of the text blocks is more than one paragraph.  i'll have to research that -- i've actually done something nearly the same, but probably 30 years ago, so a bit of archaeology is involved.

Comment: @barbarabeeton A reasonable assumption considering what this site is about, I think :) And I think I see where you're going with it, though I still think it'd be 'easiest' to use the macros to wrap the section titles with `\section{…}`.  That would save a lot of time with all the wonderful things `\@startsection` does. That's what I was trying to get at :)  (It very well may be the case that you're rather referring to some deep magic that I know not.)

Comment: @Daniel Can you make that an answer for tidiness? `:)`

Comment: @SeanAllred: Done

Answer (score 4):

While it is certainly possible (and maybe also fun) to do such transformations in (La)TeX directly, I would just employ `perl` or a similar tool that supports search & replace across multiple lines. In your case:

```
perl -0777 -i.bak -pe 's/\n\n\n(.*)\n\n/\n\n\\section{\1}\n/' plain.txt
```

will transform the file `text.txt` accordingly.

Some details:

- The `-0777` option makes `perl` read the file at once, which is necessary here to match across multiple lines.
- The file `plain.txt` will be modified "in place" (`-i` option), but a backup is created in `plain.bak` (suffix provided to `-i`).
- In the regex we search for three consecutive newlines `\n\n\n` followed by arbitrary text `(.*)` that is terminated by two newlines `\n\n`.
- In the replace part we insert two newlines `\n\n` followed by the `\section{...}` command and another newline `\n`. The `\1` is substituted with the first bracketed expression of the search regex, which in this case is the matched "arbitrary text".

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you need to interpret every paragraphs (separated by blank line) as a section title if such paragraph preceedes exactly two blank lines. You can try this:

```
\def\par{\endgraf\futurelet\next\parA}
\def\parA{\ifx\next\par \expandafter\sect\fi}
\long\def\sect#1#2\par{\bigskip{\bf #2}\par\nobreak\medskip}

block of text


section title

first paragraph block of text block of text block of text

second paragraph block of text block of text block of text


sect2 title

next paragraph block of text block of text block of text

\bye
```

But this code is very fragile. You can try to insert two blank lines before `\bye` for example and you get an error. If you insert blank lines between macros then you will have new problems, if there are two consecutive blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++, use the extended search mode and look for three return to line you entered (two empty lines) using

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

Replace it by

```
\r\n\r\n\r\n\section{
```

close the \section command by knowing that \r\n\r\n" follows. Replace

```
\r\n\r\n"
```

by

```
}\r\n"
```

You will then transform

```
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)


Title

"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)
```

to:

```
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)

\section{Title}
"lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." (A block of text.)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer alexandre-willame. I'm using a Mac, so I can't install Notepad++, but Daniel's suggestion worked.

Comment: @ProcessingText And a voice whispered in the darkness… "AUCTeX…"